# do apple devices support windows media player

Tags: ios, mp3, wmp

I have a podcast page where the mp3 podcasts are played in an 
"object" tag using windows Media Player. But they don't work in iPhone, iPad and iTouch. Is it because apple devices don't support WMP ?

Do I need to use HTML5 for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Apple won't support Microsoft products.

Also if you are creating cross platform application there will be such kind of chanllenges.

I would recommend using Flow Player, I have used it my past projects and it works like charm

http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/javascript/ipad.html